# Html5 application cache not working correctly on iPhone

Tags: ios, html

I'm trying to build a web-application shopping list.
I want to use the html5 application cache to view the list when offline.
The shopping list items are stored in local storage.
On my laptop everything works fine but on my iPhone, it seems that all pages are cached while this is not my purpose.

```
I have three pages:
index.html: page with the login form
list.html: page to add items to the list
offline.html: page to view the list when offline (f.e. during shopping)
```

My manifest file (offline.appcache) looks like follows and is included in the html-tag in index.html and list.html:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 24/05/2017 16:55:23
CACHE:
/shopping-app/offline.html
/shopping-app/offline.js
/includes/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
/includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
NETWORK:
*
FALLBACK:
/shopping-app/*.html /shopping-app/offline.html
```

The purpose was that when you whould visit index.html or list.html when offline, you whould see offline.html.
This worked on my laptop but not on Safari on iPhone. Although offline.html was cached correctly but the redirection to it failed.

So I added the following line in my javascript:

```
if(((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
|| (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) 
&& navigator.onLine === false) 
document.location.href = "/shopping-app/offline.html";
```

So far it worked but since I included the manifest in index.html and list.html, these pages where cached as well. When I now change the list on list.html, the changes aren't visible on my iPhone.

So I added the following lines in the headers of index.html and list.html, but without any effect:

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Any idea to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Kristof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I found a solution that works for me.
I discovered that the application cache feature is not yet totally supported by all browsers.
With the help of the link below I came to a working solution.
It's not the most elegant solution but it works in Firefox, Edge and Safari.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

```
Since every page with a manifest attribute in the html tag will be cached, I renamed the following pages:
- index.html became login.html
- offline.html became index.html
```

Only the index.html page has a manifest-attribute.
This page contains the offline shopping list.
The javascript of this page checks if online.
When online, it checks if a new application cache needs to be downloaded and if done, redirects to the login.html page.
When offline, the page just shows the shopping list.

Below the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(navigator.onLine === false) {

        // Offline

        loadShoppingList();

    }else{

        // Online

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener("error",function(e) {

            // Error, probably because of offline       

            loadShoppingList();

        },false);

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener("cached",function(e) {

            // Cached for the first time        

            document.location.href = "/shopping-app/login.html";

        },false);

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener("noupdate",function(e) {

            // No update

            document.location.href = "/shopping-app/login.html";

        },false);

        window.applicationCache.addEventListener("updateready",function(e) {

            if(window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {

                // New manifest downloaded: redirect to online version

                window.applicationCache.swapCache();        
                document.location.href = "/shopping-app/login.html";

            } // end if

        },false);

    } // end if

}); // end ready

function loadShoppingList() {

    if($("#order_div").hasClass("hidden")) {

        $("#wait_div").addClass("hidden");
        $("#order_div").removeClass("hidden");

    } // end if

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") $("#order_div").html(localStorage.getItem("order_table"));

} // end function
```

For now, this seems to work, but I have to do practical testings to see if it works smooth anough.

Greetings,
Kristof